# Add img tag to a button rendered by php function

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to add an `<img>` tag to a button (inside the button) that is created/rendered by a php function.

Inside that function, in the end, I have this:

```
return $environment->render('WizardBundle:Participation:ssa.html.twig', $parameters);
```

ssa.html.twig has:

```
{% if url is defined %}
    <a href="{{ url }}" {{ attributes|raw }}><img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/images/image.png') }}">{{ label|trans({}, 'wizard') }}</a>
{% else %}
    <p>{{ label }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

I tried to add the tag inside the `<a>`, but nothing shows up.
Do I need to modify anything in that php function (can post if needed)?

Comment: have you checked the generated html ? is it properly formatted ? Is your asset properly loaded (you can check in your network). This should work if there isn't any typo. I can see that the html `<img>` is not closed btw, you should add a `</img>` before the `</a>` and see if that works

Comment: @Unex yah, it looks just like before and there are no errors in the console/network. Even with that tag change, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
$parameters = [
    'url' => 'http://google.es',
    'attributes' => 'target="_blank"',
    'label' => 'button',
    'assetsPath' => ''
];
```

on template:

```
{% if url is defined %}
    <a href="{{ url }}" {{ attributes|raw }}>
        <button><img src="{{ asset(assetsPath ~ '/images/image.png') }}"> {{ label }}</a></button>
    </a>
{% else %}
    <p>{{ label }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

If don't work for you, can you put the full code?